# Adding custom class elements into TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I will try to explain what I've been trying to do and couldn't figure it out as simple as possible (using cars for example). Let's say that I have a custom made class (which could also have more than three elements) in my MainWindw.xaml.cs code:

```
    public class Car {
        public string car_name { get; set; }
        public string car_brand { get; set; }
        public int car_year { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I would like to implement Car into a TreeView, which should look something like this:

```
    ->car_name
       ->car_brand
       ->car_year
```

So when I click on car_name, it expands and car_brand and car_year are it's sub elements. I also want to be able to add multiple of those, e.g.:

```
    ->car_name
       ->car_brand
       ->car_year
    ->car_name
       ->car_brand
       ->car_year
    ->car_name
       ->car_brand
       ->car_year
```

What I can not figure out is what is the proper way of implementing my custom made class into TreeView using C#. I have tried many variants of "Binding". There are numerous examples on the internet, but I haven't come across any which would be really simplified, or I've been looking at this for too long and gone a bit mad and unable to see through it.

```
    <TreeView Name="myTree">
        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding car_name}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding car_brand}"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding car_year}"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

C# as I imagine it should go something like this when I want to add a new car:

```
    Car mycar1 = new Car({car_name="my car name", car_brand="my car brand", car_year=1999});
    myTree.Add(mycar1);
```

I would love it if anyone could explain this to me in simple terms. I just started learning C# and XAML using VisualStudio and it is really bugging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simply done this way without the Binding:

```
           Car mycar1 = new Car("my car name", "my car brand", 1999);
           TreeViewItem node = new TreeViewItem() { Header = mycar1.car_name};
           node.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = mycar1.car_brand });
           node.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = mycar1.car_year });
           myTree.Items.Add(node);
```

every node is the car name and to the node you add the brand and year and then add the whole node to the tree like done above.
note this is the Car class I used:

```
public class Car
{
    public string car_name { get; set; }
    public string car_brand { get; set; }
    public int car_year { get; set; }
    public Car(string name, string brand, int year)
    {
        car_brand = brand;
        car_name = name;
        car_year = year;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great! Is there also a simple way for this to get the node you click on? For example, using MouseLeftButtonUp="myTree_MouseLeftButtonUp" function in myTree?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, when the user clicks on the name of the car you wan to know which one was clicked?

Comment: Yes, so for example, if user click on the first car, a picture of that car is displayed somewhere on the grid of the application, and if user clicks on another car in the TreeView, picture of that car is displayed.

Comment: you can add  node.MouseLeftButtonUp += node_MouseLeftButtonUp;
and  private void node_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender,            MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //do what you want here
        }